# How to create a Navigation Navigation Bar that becomes fixed at the top after scrolling in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have been doing some research on how to create a navigation bar that get's fixed to the top after scrolling, quite similar to the music app or weather app from Apple as shown below. No need to post the code if it's long and laborious but a link or some direction would be great.[image]

[image]

Comment: NavigationBar is always attached to the top, not sure what behaviour you want, if you would like to hide navigation bar on scroll then use self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true

Comment: If you are creating a UINavigationBar directly, that might be your first problem. Try using a UINavigationController and push your ViewController(s) onto it's stack. You can still customise the appearance of the UINavigationBar.

Comment: I think that could have been the problem, creating the navBar Directly. Will try with the UINavController Stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think what the music app is actually doing is fading away the table view's section header, and then change the navigation bar's title to the appropriate words. To change the navigation bar's title you can do something like this:

```
self.navigationItem.title = "Flame On"
```

And if you want to add a custom view to your navigation bar (maybe some buttons), you can do this:

```
let myView = UIView()
// Customize myView
self.navigationItem.titleView = myView
```

Hope that helps.